# MongoDB mongoose update updatedAt field

Tags: javascript

```js
const days = [
  '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02',
  '2019-07-03', '2019-07-04',
  '2019-07-05', '2019-07-08',
  '2019-07-09', '2019-07-10',
  '2019-07-11', '2019-07-12',
  '2019-07-15', '2019-07-17',
  '2019-07-18', '2019-07-19',
  '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24'
]
```

I've this **Strings** array. These are actually dates. Is there a way to sort this dates string on both ascending and descending order. 
I tried these but nothing seems like working.

```
days.sort()

points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
```

How do I achieve this using JS?

Any help!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For ascending:

```
days.sort();
```

For descending:

```
days.sort().reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort each by converting them into date and comparing them, assuming they are in *YYYY-MM-DD* format:

```js
const days = [
  '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02',
  '2019-07-03', '2019-07-04',
  '2019-07-05', '2019-07-08',
  '2019-07-09', '2019-07-10',
  '2019-07-11', '2019-07-12',
  '2019-07-15', '2019-07-17',
  '2019-07-18', '2019-07-19',
  '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24'
];

console.log(days.sort((a, b) =>  new Date(a) - new Date(b))); //asc
console.log(days.sort((a, b) =>  new Date(b) - new Date(a))); //desc
```

---

```js
const days = [
  '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02',
  '2019-07-03', '2019-07-04',
  '2019-07-05', '2019-07-08',
  '2019-07-09', '2019-07-10',
  '2019-07-11', '2019-07-12',
  '2019-07-15', '2019-07-17',
  '2019-07-18', '2019-07-19',
  '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24'
];

console.log(days.sort((a, b) => {
  var d1 = a.split('-'),
    d2 = b.split('-');
  return new Date(d1[0], d1[1] - 1, d1[2]) - new Date(d2[0], d2[1] - 1, d2[2]);
  //--------------^Year--^Month-----^day
}));
console.log(days.sort((a, b) => {
  var d1 = a.split('-'),
    d2 = b.split('-');
  return new Date(d2[0], d2[1] - 1, d2[2]) - new Date(d1[0], d1[1] - 1, d1[2]);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have two functions to sort dates in both ascending and descending order.

```
var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {
  if (new Date(date1) > new Date(date2)) return 1;
  if (new Date(date1) < new Date(date2)) return -1;
  return 0;
};

var date_sort_desc = function (date1, date2) {
  if (new Date(date1) > new Date(date2)) return -1;
  if (new Date(date1) < new Date(date2)) return 1;
  return 0;
};
```

Now you can sort them by calling these functions as a callback inside sort function like -

```
days.sort(date_sort_asc);
days.sort(date_sort_desc);
```